# PHP let users only access their ID page

Tags: php, session, redirect

So I have this page that's personal for every person.
I don't want people to change the ID of the URL so that they can access others.

```
echo '<th>Page:</th><td>' . $_SESSION['memberID'] . '</th> <td><a href="page.php?memberID=' . $_SESSION['memberID'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
```

When they press edit they get redirected to the page /page.php?memberID=1 <- depends on their ID.

What I've added to page.php

```
header('Location: page.php?memberID=' . $_SESSION['memberID'] . '');
```

The URL link is correct but it it's not working. Chrome will display "This page isn’t working".

Comment: A 500 error code? Enable error-reporting and see what the actual error is. `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);`

Comment: Did you start the session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just created an infinite loop. what you want is ...

```
if($_GET['memberID'] != $_SESSION['memberID']){
    header('Location: page.php?memberID=' . $_SESSION['memberID'] . '');
    die;
}
```

I would also like to point out that if only the member can access this page, you don't even need the GET string you can omit that and just use their SESSION to pull in their information.